# Les gardiens sont (des) ennemis des artisans

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Je ne lui dis pas que les gardiens sont **des** ennemis des artisans.

Il est impossible d'omettre l'article indéfini devant "ennemis" en raison de "des artisans". Est-ce correct ?

Comment: Est-ce que ce sont les seuls (ou les principaux) ennemis ?

Comment: @jlliagre Oui... Il y a deux groupes principaux, gardiens et artisans. Donc, il faut employer "les" devant "ennemis" ?

Comment: Oui, c'est le meilleur choix.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais "des" n'est pas incorrect ?

Comment: Non, ce n'est pas incorrect. *Des ennemis* sous entend cependant que ce sont des ennemis parmi d'autres.

Answer (score 3):

C'est un usage qui se trouve de moins en moins. Pour s'en convaicre il suffit de consulter cet [ngram-ci](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+ennemis+des+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csont%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csont%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0) et les [pages d'exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sont+ennemis+des%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=Pt2TYd3vKq_DlwS-nafoBw&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjdhrjVp530AhWv4YUKHb7OCX04ZBDy0wN6BAgBEEE&biw=975&bih=1008&dpr=1).

[image]

Néanmoins, on peut toujours utiliser cette forme sans « des ». On voit d'après les livres Google que le fait qu'il y ait « des » avant « artisans » n'a aucune incidence sur l'utilisation de « des » avant « ennemi ». On peut l'utiliser comme on peut s'en passer, mais de nos jours malgré le déclin de la forme sans « des » c'est celle qui est le plus souvent utilisée. ([ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+des+ennemis+des+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csont%20des%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csont%20des%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0), [ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+ennemis+des%2Csont+des+ennemis+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csont%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csont%20des%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csont%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csont%20des%20ennemis%20des%3B%2Cc0)).

[image]

[image]

Ne pas négliger que « les » et « un des » sont aussi des possibilités (selon le contexte).

- Je ne lui dis pas que les gardiens sont *les* ennemis des artisans.
- Je ne lui dis pas que les gardiens sont *un des* ennemis des artisans.

Comment: J'éviterais ***Les** gardiens sont **un** des ennemis*.

Comment: @jlliagre Évidemment, ça parait un peu bizarre, mais on trouve de nombreux exemples :  « Les passions de la jeunesse sont un ennemi que vous devez apprendre à fuir — les communistes sont un ennemi extrêmement tenace — c'est que ces derniers sont un ennemi qui profite — Les « vauriens » sont un ennemi qu'il faut combattre à main armée —l'Impérialisme et le Colonialisme sont un ennemi commun — Ils sont un ennemi auquel on peut échapper — les Frères musulmans sont un ennemi irréductible … ».

Comment: On en trouve peut-être des exemples, mais j'éviterais quand même.

Comment: @jlliagre Ce n'est pas « peut-être », et ça ne date pas d'hier : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+un+ennemi&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3.

Comment: Je ne suis pas très convaincu : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+un+des+ennemis&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=

Comment: @jlliagre Ça n'est qu'un cas particulier : (1/2)

Comment: @jlliagre https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+un+des+%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csont%20un%20des%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9ments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20principaux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20moyens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20traits%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20meilleurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20caract%C3%A8res%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20grands%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20premiers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsont%20un%20des%20facteurs%3B%2Cc0 (2/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131502/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lph).